# query_cache_type: enable or disable?

Tags: mysql, wordpress, percona

Recently, I moved from standard MySQL to `Percona`, and used the [Percona Wizard](https://tools.percona.com/wizard) to generate `my.cnf`.

However, I  can see that, by default, the generated settings for `my.cnf` use `query_cache_type = 0`. (query cache is disabled).

The only thing I run on the server is a Wordpress blog. My questions are:

1. May I enable query cache?
2. There are some Wordpress plugins that offer database cache. Is the result similar of enabling query cache?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

MySQL query cache is a cache mechanism that stores the text of the query (e.g. 'SELECT * FROM users WHERE deleted = 0') and the result of the query into memory. Please check [this link](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/enable-the-query-cache-in-mysql-to-improve-performance.html) to know how to enable mysql query cache in your server.

The wordpress [DB cache plugins](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/db-cache-reloaded/faq/) on the other hand,  decreases count of queries to DB by caching queries in temp files (Check your cache directory wp-content/tmp/ for cache files).

Above two paragraphs prove that Wordpress db cache  AND mysql query cache are different.

mysql query cache you should enable ONLY IF your site does more mysql reads than writes. since yours is a wordpress site, YES you can try by enabling mysql query cache.

Hope I answered your 2 questions.

Comment: Hi @André Bazaglia Please let me know if this helps.